# Convert IBM Lotus Notes file to text

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus, file-conversion

How can I convert an .nsf lotus file to a text file? i want to write a java program to read .nsf file which is on my system. i have tried it simply but it is showing non english character is their any way to get access them normaly.

EDIT:

That code is in .net and using any server's session, I just want to read .nsf file by java without creating any server's session in fact i have .nsf database. i just want to read as a text file.if there a way to parse .nsf with javacc,it would be better enough......

Comment: You're not giving us enough information.  Are you trying to write a program yourself to do this, or are you looking for a piece of software to do it for you?

Answer (score 5):

lotus notes database is full of proprietary design components. Assuming you just want to export the data, you will need to write an agent, (aka batch process), that would look at all documents in the database and then export all the fields into a plain text file.

If you're into XML, you can export data in that format as well, but again, you will need to write an agent for that.

Alternatively, there are some basic builtin mechanisms in Lotus Notes to export data but this is restricted to running them from views. Views do no necessarily get all the documents. You can design a view to do that though.

Providing the size of the database is not extremely large, (less than 200k documents), you can create view listing all the columns you want to export and a view formula that has "Select @All", will give you all documents. Then, the "quickest" way to get data out from a view can be found [here](http://www.codestore.net/help/help85_designer.nsf/b3266a3c17f9bb7085256b870069c0a9/851b9ecabad7179e852574cf006b36ed?OpenDocument) using simple export procedure.

There is still the issues of exporting rich media, you can have a look [here](http://www.nsftools.com/tips/NotesTips.htm#rtfexport) for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can export some data easily by selecting all the documents in a view, and then going to Edit > Copy Selected As Table.  Then just paste the content into Excel or a text file.

To access the data beyond what is showing in a view, you can try a few other things:

- Connect to the data using the NotesSQL driver
- Connect via the COM api (using Java, C#, VB, etc)
- Create some views in Lotus Notes that DO have the data you need, and use my recommendation above.
- Install and and my [Export to Excel application](http://partialclass.blogspot.com/2009/02/export-to-excel-20-for-lotus-notes.html)