# How can i excel export the selected fields in lotus notes?

Tags: lotus-notes

How can i excel export the selected fields in lotus notes?

Comment: See my answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/5664479/30812

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending formatted Lotus Notes rich text email from Excel VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686384/sending-formatted-lotus-notes-rich-text-email-from-excel-vba)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the code on this site, it works well. http://partialclass.blogspot.com/2009/02/export-to-excel-20-for-lotus-notes.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.